state is not properly updated when using with `tanstack-query`
I have an Uploader component that can be both controlled and uncontrolled. The instantUpload prop allows for immidiate update once the files are chosen. Unfortunately, for some reason the files variable is not updated properly in onUploadProgress and onSuccess callback (i.e. files is an empty array instead of a chosen file). Any reason why is that a case?
'use client';

import { ChangeEvent, RefObject, createContext, useRef, useState } from 'react';

import { useSaveFile } from '@/api/file/hooks';
import { useToast } from '@/components/ui/use-toast';
import { DefaultUploadContainer } from '@/components/uploader/default-upload-container';
import { DefaultUploadTrigger } from '@/components/uploader/default-upload-trigger';
import { formatFileSize, getFileExtension } from '@/lib/utils';
import { UploadedFile } from '@/types';
import { DefaultExtensionType } from 'react-file-icon';

export type UploaderFile = {
  file?: globalThis.File;
  src: string;
  extension: DefaultExtensionType;
  progress?: number;
  uploading?: boolean;
  name: string;
  size: number;
  id?: string;
  uploadedFile?: UploadedFile;
};

interface UploaderContext {
  files: UploaderFile[];
  onChange: (files: UploaderFile[]) => void;
  handleUpload: (file: UploaderFile) => void;
  handleRemoveFile: (file: UploaderFile) => void;
  fileInputRef: RefObject<HTMLInputElement>;
}

export const UploaderContext = createContext<UploaderContext>({} as any);

export interface UploaderProps {
  allowedExtensions?: DefaultExtensionType[];
  multiple?: boolean;
  instantUpload?: boolean;
  files?: UploaderFile[];
  defaultFiles?: UploaderFile[];
  maxSize?: number;
  onChange?: (files: UploaderFile[]) => void;
  onClick?: (file: UploaderFile) => void;
  triggerRenderer?: () => JSX.Element;
  containerRenderer?: () => JSX.Element;
  Trigger?: React.ComponentType;
  Container?: React.ComponentType;
}
export function Uploader({
  multiple = true,
  allowedExtensions,
  instantUpload = true,
  maxSize,
  files: valueFromProps,
  defaultFiles: defaultValue,
  Trigger,
  Container,
  onChange: onChangeFromProps,
}: UploaderProps) {
  // A component can be considered controlled when its value prop is
  // not undefined.
  const isControlled = typeof valueFromProps != 'undefined';
  // When a component is not controlled, it can have a defaultValue.
  const hasDefaultValue = typeof defaultValue != 'undefined';

  // If a defaultValue is specified, we will use it as our initial
  // state.  Otherwise, we will simply use an empty array.
  const [internalValue, setInternalValue] = useState<UploaderFile[]>(
    hasDefaultValue ? defaultValue : []
  );

  // Internally, we need to deal with some value. Depending on whether
  // the component is controlled or not, that value comes from its
  // props or from its internal state.
  let files: UploaderFile[];
  if (isControlled) {
    files = valueFromProps;
  } else files = internalValue;

  const onChange = (value: UploaderFile[]) => {
    // If exists, we always call onChange callback passed in props
    // We do this even if there is no props.value (and the component
    // is uncontrolled.)
    if (onChangeFromProps) {
      onChangeFromProps(value);
    }

    // If the component is uncontrolled, we need to update our
    // internal value here.
    if (!isControlled) {
      setInternalValue(value);
    }
  };

  const fileInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  const mutationUploadFile = useSaveFile({});
  const { toast } = useToast();

  const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    let inputFiles: UploaderFile[] = Array.from(event.target.files || []).map(
      (file) => ({
        file: file,
        name: file.name,
        size: file.size,
        src: URL.createObjectURL(file),
        extension: getFileExtension(file.name),
      })
    );
    if (!inputFiles.length) return;

    if (!multiple && files.length !== 0) {
      toast({
        title: 'Zbyt wiele plików!',
        description: <div>Możesz przesłać maksymalnie jeden plik!</div>,
        variant: 'destructive',
      });
      return;
    }

    for (let file of inputFiles) {
      if (!file.file) continue;
      if (allowedExtensions && !allowedExtensions.includes(file.extension)) {
        toast({
          title: 'Nieprawidłowy format pliku!',
          description: (
            <div className='w-full max-w-full'>
              <p>
                Dozwolone są jedynie pliki w nastepujących formatach:{' '}
                <span className='font-bold'>
                  {allowedExtensions.map((x) => x.toUpperCase()).join(', ')}.
                </span>
              </p>
              <p className='pt-2'>
                Pominięto plik: <span className='italic'>{file.file.name}</span>
              </p>
            </div>
          ),
          variant: 'destructive',
        });
        inputFiles = inputFiles.filter((item) => item.name !== file.name);
      }
      if (maxSize && file.file.size > maxSize) {
        toast({
          title: 'Zbyt duży rozmiar pliku!',
          description: (
            <div>
              Rozmiar pliku <span className='italic'>{file.file.name}</span> (
              {formatFileSize(file.file.size)}) przekracza maksymalny dozwolony
              rozmiar{' '}
              <span className='font-bold'>({formatFileSize(maxSize)})</span>
            </div>
          ),
          variant: 'destructive',
        });
        inputFiles = inputFiles.filter((x) => x !== file);
      }
      if (files.some((x) => x.file?.name === file.file?.name)) {
        inputFiles = inputFiles.filter((x) => x !== file);
        toast({
          title: 'Plik już istnieje!',
          description: (
            <div>
              Plik <span className='italic'>{file.file.name}</span> (
              {formatFileSize(file.file.size)}) został już dodany.
            </div>
          ),
          variant: 'destructive',
        });
      }
    }

    onChange([...files, ...inputFiles]);

    if (instantUpload) {
      for (let file of inputFiles) {
        handleUpload(file);
      }
    }

    fileInputRef.current!.value = '';
  };

  const handleUpload = (file: UploaderFile) => {
    mutationUploadFile.mutate(
      {
        file: file.file!,
        onUploadProgress(progress) {
          onChange(
            files.map((item) => {
              if (item.name === file.name)
                return {
                  ...file,
                  uploading: true,
                  progress: Math.floor(
                    (progress.loaded / progress.total!) * 100
                  ),
                };
              return item;
            })
          );
        },
      },
      {
        onSuccess(res) {
          onChange(
            files.map((item) => {
              if (item.name === file.name)
                return {
                  ...item,
                  id: res.id,
                  src: res.url,
                  uploadedFile: res,
                  uploading: false,
                };
              return item;
            })
          );
        },
        onError(error, variables, context) {},
      }
    );
  };

  const handleRemoveFile = (file: UploaderFile) => {
    if (file.uploadedFile) {
      onChange(files.filter((item) => item.name !== file.name));
    } else {
      onChange(files.filter((item) => item.name !== file.name));
    }
  };

  return (
    <UploaderContext.Provider
      value={{
        files,
        onChange,
        handleUpload,
        handleRemoveFile,
        fileInputRef,
      }}
    >
      <div className='w-full'>
        <input
          type='file'
          name='file'
          hidden
          multiple={multiple}
          ref={fileInputRef}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        {Trigger ? <Trigger /> : <DefaultUploadTrigger />}
        {Container ? <Container /> : <DefaultUploadContainer />}
      </div>
    </UploaderContext.Provider>
  );
}


EDIT
Using ref
'use client';

import { ChangeEvent, RefObject, createContext, useRef, useState } from 'react';

import { useSaveFile, useSaveGuestFile } from '@/api/file/hooks';
import { useToast } from '@/components/ui/use-toast';
import { DefaultUploadContainer } from '@/components/uploader/default-upload-container';
import { DefaultUploadTrigger } from '@/components/uploader/default-upload-trigger';
import { formatFileSize, getFileExtension } from '@/lib/utils';
import { UploadedFile } from '@/types';
import { DefaultExtensionType } from 'react-file-icon';

export type UploaderFile = {
  file?: globalThis.File;
  src: string;
  extension: DefaultExtensionType;
  progress?: number;
  uploading?: boolean;
  name: string;
  size: number;
  id?: string;
  uploadedFile?: UploadedFile;
};

interface UploaderContext {
  files: UploaderFile[];
  onChange: (files: UploaderFile[]) => void;
  handleUpload: (file: UploaderFile) => void;
  handleRemoveFile: (file: UploaderFile) => void;
  fileInputRef: RefObject<HTMLInputElement>;
}

export const UploaderContext = createContext<UploaderContext>({} as any);

export interface UploaderProps {
  allowedExtensions?: DefaultExtensionType[];
  multiple?: boolean;
  instantUpload?: boolean;
  files?: UploaderFile[];
  defaultFiles?: UploaderFile[];
  maxSize?: number;
  guest?: boolean;
  onChange?: (files: UploaderFile[]) => void;
  onClick?: (file: UploaderFile) => void;
  Trigger?: React.ComponentType;
  Container?: React.ComponentType;
}
export function Uploader({
  multiple = true,
  allowedExtensions,
  instantUpload = true,
  maxSize,
  guest,
  files: valueFromProps,
  defaultFiles: defaultValue,
  Trigger,
  Container,
  onChange: onChangeFromProps,
}: UploaderProps) {
  // A component can be considered controlled when its value prop is
  // not undefined.
  const isControlled = typeof valueFromProps != 'undefined';
  // When a component is not controlled, it can have a defaultValue.
  const hasDefaultValue = typeof defaultValue != 'undefined';

  // If a defaultValue is specified, we will use it as our initial
  // state.  Otherwise, we will simply use an empty array.
  const [internalValue, setInternalValue] = useState<UploaderFile[]>(
    hasDefaultValue ? defaultValue : []
  );

  // Internally, we need to deal with some value. Depending on whether
  // the component is controlled or not, that value comes from its
  // props or from its internal state.
  const files = useRef<UploaderFile[]>([]);
  // let files: UploaderFile[];
  if (isControlled) {
    files.current = valueFromProps;
  } else files.current = internalValue;

  const onChange = (value: UploaderFile[]) => {
    files.current = value;
    // If exists, we always call onChange callback passed in props
    // We do this even if there is no props.value (and the component
    // is uncontrolled.)
    if (onChangeFromProps) {
      onChangeFromProps(value);
    }

    // If the component is uncontrolled, we need to update our
    // internal value here.
    if (!isControlled) {
      setInternalValue(value);
    }
  };

  const fileInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  const mutationFn = guest ? useSaveGuestFile : useSaveFile;

  const mutationUploadFile = mutationFn({
    onSuccess(res) {
      onChange(
        files.current.map((item) => {
          if (item.name === res.originalname)
            return {
              ...item,
              id: res.id,
              src: res.url,
              uploadedFile: res,
              uploading: false,
            };
          return item;
        })
      );
    },
  });
  const { toast } = useToast();

  const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    let inputFiles: UploaderFile[] = Array.from(event.target.files || []).map(
      (file) => ({
        file: file,
        name: file.name,
        size: file.size,
        src: URL.createObjectURL(file),
        extension: getFileExtension(file.name),
      })
    );
    if (!inputFiles.length) return;

    if (!multiple && files.current.length !== 0) {
      toast({
        title: 'Zbyt wiele plików!',
        description: <div>Możesz przesłać maksymalnie jeden plik!</div>,
        variant: 'destructive',
      });
      return;
    }

    for (let file of inputFiles) {
      if (!file.file) continue;
      if (allowedExtensions && !allowedExtensions.includes(file.extension)) {
        toast({
          title: 'Nieprawidłowy format pliku!',
          description: (
            <div className='w-full max-w-full'>
              <p>
                Dozwolone są jedynie pliki w nastepujących formatach:{' '}
                <span className='font-bold'>
                  {allowedExtensions.map((x) => x.toUpperCase()).join(', ')}.
                </span>
              </p>
              <p className='pt-2'>
                Pominięto plik: <span className='italic'>{file.file.name}</span>
              </p>
            </div>
          ),
          variant: 'destructive',
        });
        inputFiles = inputFiles.filter((item) => item.name !== file.name);
      }
      if (maxSize && file.file.size > maxSize) {
        toast({
          title: 'Zbyt duży rozmiar pliku!',
          description: (
            <div>
              Rozmiar pliku <span className='italic'>{file.file.name}</span> (
              {formatFileSize(file.file.size)}) przekracza maksymalny dozwolony
              rozmiar{' '}
              <span className='font-bold'>({formatFileSize(maxSize)})</span>
            </div>
          ),
          variant: 'destructive',
        });
        inputFiles = inputFiles.filter((x) => x !== file);
      }
      if (files.current.some((x) => x.file?.name === file.file?.name)) {
        inputFiles = inputFiles.filter((x) => x !== file);
        toast({
          title: 'Plik już istnieje!',
          description: (
            <div>
              Plik <span className='italic'>{file.file.name}</span> (
              {formatFileSize(file.file.size)}) został już dodany.
            </div>
          ),
          variant: 'destructive',
        });
      }
    }

    onChange([...files.current, ...inputFiles]);

    if (instantUpload) {
      for (let file of inputFiles) {
        handleUpload(file);
      }
    }

    fileInputRef.current!.value = '';
  };

  const handleUpload = (file: UploaderFile) => {
    onChange(
      files.current.map((item) => {
        if (item.name === file.name)
          return {
            ...file,
            uploading: true,
          };
        return item;
      })
    );
    mutationUploadFile.mutate({
      file: file.file!,
      onUploadProgress(progress) {
        onChange(
          files.current.map((item) => {
            if (item.name === file.name)
              return {
                ...file,
                uploading: true,
                progress: Math.floor((progress.loaded / progress.total!) * 100),
              };
            return item;
          })
        );
      },
    });
  };

  const handleRemoveFile = (file: UploaderFile) => {
    if (file.uploadedFile) {
      onChange(files.current.filter((item) => item.name !== file.name));
    } else {
      onChange(files.current.filter((item) => item.name !== file.name));
    }
  };

  return (
    <UploaderContext.Provider
      value={{
        files: files.current,
        onChange,
        handleUpload,
        handleRemoveFile,
        fileInputRef,
      }}
    >
      <div className='w-full'>
        <input
          type='file'
          name='file'
          hidden
          multiple={multiple}
          ref={fileInputRef}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        {Trigger ? <Trigger /> : <DefaultUploadTrigger />}
        {Container ? <Container /> : <DefaultUploadContainer />}
      </div>
    </UploaderContext.Provider>
  );
}



You're updating state using setInternalValue(value) but you need to pass in a setter function because it's based on previous state. Otherwise, there's a risk files in the onSuccess is not up-to-date because React batches state updates.
Doing this is a bit of a challenge because you have to handle both controlled and uncontrolled use cases. A bit of refactoring may be needed, but the uncontrolled updates would look like this.
onSuccess: () => {
  if (!isControlled) {
    setInternalValue((files) =>
      files.map((item) => {
        if (item.name === file.name) {
          return {
            ...file,
            uploadedFile: res,
            uploading: false,
          };
        }
        return item;
      })
    );
  }
}


Usually a controlled input is a 'dumb' component and won't fire any API call, instead making it the responsibility of a parent component.

understood thank you :) I rewrite my component little but to store files inside a ref. It works but I wondering whether its a good approach. Could you please a look at my updated question?

Yes, the reason why your solution also works because updates to ref.current are instant, but updates to setState() are batched. I haven't tested your code but looks ok to me.
